# MPV: Get window position and size? Or window-moved/resized event?

Tags: mpv

Is there a way to get the current position and size of the MPV media player's window (or an event that fires when they are changed)?

---

I'm trying to make a script that automatically saves the last position of the window, and then loads it when the player starts. Settings the position on startup can be done with `geometry`, but reading can't.

In the log it is logged when the windows is moved:

```
[  34.308][d][vo/gpu/win32] move window: 1953:48
```

And resized:

```
[  37.990][v][vo/gpu] Resize: 1810x1004
[  37.990][v][vo/gpu] Window size: 1810x1004
```

Is there a way to get these values or callbacks in a (javascript) script? I couldn't find the event in the documentation sadly, or did I just miss it?

Only thing I could find were `dwidth` and `dheight`, but these represent only the size of the video, not the entire window nor the position of it.

Thanks!

Note: I also asked this on [mpv's github](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/6875), but no reply yet. I'll update the other when I get a reply in either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way using `mp.utils.subprocess` to run some powershell script, as mpv doesn't have any API's to get the position directly. It's a bit slow, but it does work:

(The ps1 script:)

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Window {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
}
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
"@

$Handle = (Get-Process -Id $Args[0]).MainWindowHandle
$WindowRect = New-Object RECT
$GotWindowRect = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle, [ref]$WindowRect)
ConvertTo-Json($WindowRect)
```

This then gives you a json object that has the position and size of the window. You can then use `SetWindowRect` in a similar way to set the position again. Note that this rect doesn't correspond to the thing you would set with `geometry` in mpv itself, as this rect also includes the title bar and such.

Edit:

I made a better version.

The powershell script now gets the client-rect which can be used with `geometry`, and thus opening mpv is now much smoother.

So the new powershell script:

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Window {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref POINT lpPoint);
}
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
public struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
"@

$Handle = (Get-Process -Id $Args[0]).MainWindowHandle
$WindowRect = New-Object RECT
$ClientRect = New-Object RECT
$TopLeft = New-Object POINT
$BottomRight = New-Object POINT

[Window]::GetClientRect($Handle, [ref]$ClientRect) | out-null
$TopLeft.x = $ClientRect.Left
$TopLeft.y = $ClientRect.Top
$BottomRight.x = $ClientRect.Right
$BottomRight.y = $ClientRect.Bottom

[Window]::ClientToScreen($Handle, [ref]$TopLeft) | out-null
[Window]::ClientToScreen($Handle, [ref]$BottomRight) | out-null

$WindowRect.Left = $TopLeft.x
$WindowRect.Top = $TopLeft.y
$WindowRect.Right = $BottomRight.x
$WindowRect.Bottom = $BottomRight.y

ConvertTo-Json($WindowRect)
```

Then I have a javascript plugin that calls this ps1 in a simple javascript plugin:

```
// Some setup used by both reading and writing
var dir = mp.utils.split_path(mp.get_script_file())[0]
var rect_path = mp.utils.join_path(dir, "last_window_rect.txt")

// Read last window rect if present
try {
    var rect_json = mp.utils.read_file(rect_path)
    var rect = JSON.parse(rect_json)

    var width = rect.Right - rect.Left
    var height = rect.Bottom - rect.Top
    mp.set_property("screen", 0)
    mp.set_property("geometry", width + "x" + height + "+" + rect.Left + "+" + rect.Top)
}
catch (e) {
    dump(e)
}

// Save the rect at shutdown
function save_rect() {
    var ps1_script = mp.utils.join_path(dir, "Get-Client-Rect.ps1")
    var rect_json = mp.utils.subprocess({ args: ["powershell", "&(\"" + ps1_script + "\")", mp.utils.getpid()], cancellable: false }).stdout
    mp.utils.write_file("file://" + rect_path, rect_json)
}
mp.register_event("shutdown", save_rect)
```

You can also find these scripts on my github: https://github.com/TheOddler/mpv-config/tree/master/scripts but I can't promise these will stay the same forever.

Comment: Were you able to find a window move/resize event?

Comment: This was a while ago, but I think I just saved the position once when closing mpv, and loaded it when opening it. So I don't use move/resize events. Though check the documentation for `[Window]::GetClientRect` stuff, there might be something you can use there.

Comment: I need this feature in Ubuntu.