# Check window position in batch

Tags: batch-file

On Batch script, How to get X and Y from Start to End of the Window without using third party software like [Cmdow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line

Comment: Does this do what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554007/mpv-get-window-position-and-size-or-window-moved-resized-event  It requires powershell but that's built in so it isn't third party.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes but how would it be part of one batch script ?

Comment: If you must have exactly only one file then this talks about embedding the powershell script inside the batch file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609985/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-within-a-windows-batch-file  Or is it ok to have a separate powershell script file and just call it from the vatch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, combining answers from:

- https://superuser.com/questions/74620/is-there-a-way-to-get-access-to-a-window-handle-in-windows-using-wsh-or-wmi-or
- [MPV: Get window position and size? Or window-moved/resized event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554007/mpv-get-window-position-and-size-or-window-moved-resized-event)
- [How to run a PowerShell script within a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609985/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-within-a-windows-batch-file)

I came up with this:

```
<# : batch portion (begins PowerShell multi-line comment block)

set TITLE=Untitled - Notepad
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%a in ('powershell -NoProfile -NoLogo "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') DO (
    set LEFT=%%a
    set TOP=%%b
    set RIGHT=%%c
    set BOTTOM=%%d
)
echo LEFT=%LEFT% TOP=%TOP% RIGHT=%RIGHT% BOTTOM=%BOTTOM%

@GOTO :EOF
: end batch / begin PowerShell #>

Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class Window {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
}
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
"@

$Handle = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -match $env:TITLE } | ForEach-Object { $_.MainWindowHandle }
if ( $Handle -is [System.Array] ) { $Handle = $Handle[0] }
$WindowRect = New-Object RECT
$GotWindowRect = [Window]::GetWindowRect($Handle, [ref]$WindowRect)
Write-Host $WindowRect.Left $WindowRect.Top $WindowRect.Right $WindowRect.Bottom
```

Comment: Thank You! I loop over the batch it is slow but they is probably no shorcut to C. `:Loop <#..` to `..%BOTTOM% GOTO Loop`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

You can set the location by changing the cords in following line `cscript //nologo "%temp%\pos.vbs" "%~F0" 75 15`

NOTE: In this instance 75x pixels from the left and 15x pixels from the top.

```
@echo off &cls
mode con: cols=70 lines=15 &color f0

:: - Position the CMD Window Using .VBS -----------------------------------------
:: == MUST be at the beginning of the Batch =====================================
   IF "%~1" == "RestartedByVBS" Goto :Code

   :: Create the VBScript, if not exist
   if not exist "%temp%\pos.vbs" (
      (for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('findstr "^VBS:" ^< "%~F0"') do (
         echo(%%b
      )) > "%temp%\pos.vbs"
   )
   cscript //nologo "%temp%\pos.vbs" "%~F0" 75 15
   exit /b
:code
if exist "%temp%\pos.vbs" ( del /q "%temp%\pos.vbs" )
:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

echo. The rest of your batch script here.

echo. Press any key to exit &>nul timeout /t -1 &exit /B








:: - Position the CMD Window Using .VBS -----------------------------------------
:Pos <BatchFileName> <X_Coordinate> <Y_Coordinate>

:: This Function will take three inputs: The name of the Batch file to execute
:: and the X and Y Coordinates to Position its CMD window

VBS: Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
VBS: Set objConfig = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
VBS: objConfig.SpawnInstance_
VBS: objConfig.X = WScript.Arguments(1)
VBS: objConfig.Y = WScript.Arguments(2)
VBS: Set objNewProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
VBS: intReturn = objNewProcess.Create( chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(0) &chr(34)& " RestartedByVBS", Null, objConfig, intProcessID)
:: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Disclaimer: Originally posted in this thread: [Positioning CMD Window](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4285).